# creating a callback function and wiring it up

Tags: javascript

This is not a jquery question.

I want to create a callback function...so users would use it like so:

```
myfunc.init('id',{option1: val, option2: val2}, function() {

//in here users can now call methods of myfunc 

});
```

How do I do this within my code. OS once I know my script is ready I want to be able to somehow call this anonymous function.

Hope this makes sense. I often don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write i t like this:

```
var myfunc.init(id, options, callbackFunction){

//do whatever you want with id & options

callbackFunction();

}
```

This will first run everything you want in your init function then run the function supplied as the callback parameter

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var myfunc.init = function(id, options, func) {
    // call func somewhere at some point
    func();
};
```

Usually callbacks are used because you want to call it at some point at time which is unknown (asynch)... like for example when an AJAX request is complete:

```
var myfunc.init = function(id, options, func) {
    myAjaxRequest("url.com", function() { 
        // call the func at this point in time
        func();
    });
};
```

Comment: THanks, I'm waiting for the youtube api to tell me the player is ready. When it is then I want to allow the user to cue new videos/shift playback head etc.